# Pagination in vanilla Javascript without any frameworks or libraries

Tags: javascript, arrays, pagination

Stackoverflow! I got a task to create sortable/dynamic table with options to add and remove content and I've managed to do it. My last task however is to make a pagination of 20 rows per page and that's where my 10 days Javascript knowledge is put to a high test. Namely, I can't even put my foot of the ground.

Can anyone help me out in understanding the logic behind the creation of pagination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the code for paginating your table for 20 elements per page:

Edit the function loadTableData() with this:

```
//Pagination
function loadTableData(movieData, page_size, page_number) {
  // human-readable page numbers usually start with 1, so we reduce 1 in the first argument
 var movieDatap = movieData.slice((page_number - 1) * page_size, page_number * page_size);

      const tableBody = document.getElementById('tableData');
    let txt = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < movieDatap.length; i++) {
    
        txt = txt + `<tr><td>${movieDatap[i].name}</td>
                         <td>${movieDatap[i].genre}</td><td>${movieDatap[i].rating}</td>
                         <td><button onclick="deleteRow(${i});">Delete</button>
                         <button onclick="editRow(${i});">Edit</button></td></tr>`;
                               
}                                                     

    tableBody.innerHTML = txt;
  
}
function decreaseTableDatas(){
var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('pagenumber').value, 10);
 value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value--;
        document.getElementById('pagenumber').value = value;
 loadTableData(movieData, 20, value);
}
function incrementTableDatas(){
var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('pagenumber').value, 10);
 value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
        document.getElementById('pagenumber').value = value;
 loadTableData(movieData, 20, value);
}

window.onload = () => {
    loadTableData(movieData, 20, 1);
}
```

Update the HTML with this:

```
  <div class="pagination">
     <div class="pagination-block">
        <span class="pageButton outline-none" onclick="decreaseTableDatas()" id="button_prev">Prev</span>
        <input type="button" value="1" id="pagenumber" />
        <span class="pageButton outline-none" onclick="incrementTableDatas()" id="button_next">Next</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I hope that is what you are looking for mate

Comment: Thank you, or should I say "Hvala ti mnogo!" :) This is it. 

I've manage to understand HTML, CSS and Bootstrap in like 20 days to a degree that I can make fully functional pleasing on the eye sites, but for the last 7-8 days I've been struggling mightily with Javascript.

Comment: Keep learning, after all, Javascript is a programming language, focus on understanding the basics and how everything works, from then on, it will be a lot easier. If my code matched your expectation, you can mark my answer as the correct answer for the question, so the other people who see your question, will know that :)

Comment: If only my employee had your patience :) I basically got month and a half deadline to be project ready. That combined with my regular job.. shees, I feel like my head is about to explode :)

Comment: I feel you bro, but be patient, it will be all good, programming is amazing, keep going :)